# Is ggmap broken? Basic qmap() produces "arguments imply differing number of rows: 0,1"

Tags: r, ggmap

I've used ggmap many times in the past to produce maps with a particular coordinate as the focal point. It has generally been as simple as defining the focal point via the **location=** argument in **qmap()**, and adding on geoms to the map as needed.

Today, I opened ggmap for the first time in a while, and it simply is not successful in performing the most basic of mapping tasks.

```
    devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap") #Making sure I'm up-to-date
    library(ggmap)
    qmap(location = "White House", zoom = 14, source = "osm")
```

Produces the following error:

```
#Error in data.frame(ll.lat = ll[1], ll.lon = ll[2], ur.lat = ur[1], ur.lon = ur[2])
 : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

I've been digging around for hours. I tried using **get_map()** instead, but it produces the same error.

Any ideas?

**Update #1**

I've gone as far as a clean install of R/RStudio, re-installing packages from a clean slate (devtools, tidyverse, ggmap). Still, the error persists.

**Update #2**

No luck in getting the location to be automatically geocoded in process of `get_map()` as I was hoping via ggmap commands.

I've resorted to manually specifying the lat/lon coordinates of the focal point of this map.

```
qmap(location=c(lon=-77.035,lat=38.897), zoom = 14, source = "google")
```

Thanks [camille](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5325862/camille) for reminding me that there are known issues with the Open Street Map (osm) source *(& for generally troubleshooting through this with me).*

I've tried on a few different machines, on a few different networks just because it appears that some people have had local network/computer issues at the root of this problem. Now wondering if anyone is able to specify location in `qmap()` without lat/lon coordinates anymore, or if this problem is unique to me.

Comment: In order to get a map from a location name, `ggmap` has to look up & geocode the location, which I believe it does using Google's API (even if you aren't using Google map tiles). But the API changed at some point, so it seems that you need an API key registered to use it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did not mention this above because I thought the issues to be unrelated since I'm not getting any geocode failures. But, I have loaded my api key using **register_google(key ="xxx")**. I've confirmed that it is associated with my R session by checking **ggmap_credentials()**. This unfortunately doesn't change anything, and I continue to get this error.

Comment: Try rolling back to the latest CRAN release or a previous github one

Comment: @camille Thanks again. Previous builds of **ggmap** do not have the `register_google()` feature, which as you point out is necessary for the geocoding component of the `get_map()`/`qmap()` commands. 

So, when I roll back, I unfortunately end up with a different issue: **Error in download.file(...) : cannot open URL**

Comment: In previous versions, most functions should have or inherit a `key` argument

Comment: You also might just need to use a different tile provider; I know there's been bugs with OSM in the past. I'd also recommend combing through issues on the package Github

Answer (score 6):

*Updated 2019-04-06:*

=============================================

Alternative solution for using `ggmap` **with geocoding, but without the Google API**:

```
library(ggmap)
library(tmaptools)
ggmap(get_stamenmap(rbind(as.numeric(paste(geocode_OSM("Vienna")$bbox))), zoom = 11))
```

[image: Vienna Map]

Comment: Great solution!  It removes the step of going out to manually grab the coordinates. I like that `geocode_OSM()` produces a df of spatial data points from which I can grab `coords`, which is the way `get_googlemap()` likes it's center to be specified. `rbind(as.numeric(paste(geocode_OSM("Location")$coords)))`