# R, free maps similar to ggmap

Tags: r, graph, ggmap, network-analysis

In performing network analysis, I want to plot network graph on maps. Ggmap seems the first choice, but it require API access.

Is there any free and equivalent/alternative (to ggmap) options that don’t require API access?

Thank you.

Comment: `ggmap` can use other sources aside from Google Maps. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52710855/9406040) is a method to use it with `tmaptools:: geocode_OSM()` for geocoding names into coordinates and `get_stamenmap()` for the map itself, requiring no API access.

Comment: @Roman, thanks for the great input!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Street Map should suit your needs. Here is a package for it: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/OpenStreetMap/index.html. More information: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_Scientific_Tools

Comment: thank you for the information. great contribution to the community!